# Panel background image wont change on command?

Tags: c#, timer, bitmap, panel

I have a game and that whenever you shoot, it activates a timer for the bullet. In the timer (the bit that will be the following code) it detects if the bullet's bounds intersect with the enemy's bounds. If so, make the enemy red for a second, then change him back.
The following code is what I have at the bottom of the timer:

```
            if (Bullet.Bounds.IntersectsWith(Enemy.Bounds))
            {
                if (isProne)
                {
                    Enemy.BackgroundImage = TheEnemyHurt;
                    Bullet.Location = new Point(421, 236);
                    Bullet.Visible = false;
                    shooting = false;
                    Enemy.BackgroundImage = TheEnemy;
                    bulletTimer.Stop();
                }
                else if (!isProne)
                {
                    Enemy.BackgroundImage = TheEnemyHurt;
                    Bullet.Location = new Point(515, 143);
                    Bullet.Visible = false;
                    shooting = false;
                    Enemy.BackgroundImage = TheEnemy;
                    bulletTimer.Stop();
                }
            }
```

But It just keeps it as the regular enemy image (TheEnemy)
TheEnemy and TheEnemyHurt are both bitmaps at the top of the code:

```
    Bitmap TheEnemy = new Bitmap(Resources.Enemy_Bigger_);
    Bitmap TheEnemyHurt = new Bitmap(Resources.EnemyHurt_Bigger_);
```

I just dont know why it stays as the regular image, and doesnt turn to the hurt one for a second? Thank you!

Comment: It doesn't look like there's anything that's stopping/pausing the BackgroundImage from switching back and forth instantly.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem is that you are changing the panel BG *but immediately changing it back*. You are doing:

```
Enemy.BackgroundImage = TheEnemyHurt;
Bullet.Location = new Point(421, 236);
Bullet.Visible = false;
shooting = false;
Enemy.BackgroundImage = TheEnemy;
```

So you are changing the background, but change it back probably before the screen even refreshes. What you could try is use another timer like this (Pseudo-Code):

bulletTimer:

```
Enemy.BackgroundImage = TheEnemyHurt;
Bullet.Location = new Point(421, 236);
Bullet.Visible = false;
shooting = false;
bulletTimer.Stop();
hurttimer.Start();
```

hurttimer:

```
Enemy.BackgroundImage = TheEnemy;
hurttimer.Stop();
```

Depending on what you set the `hurttimer`'s interval to, that's how long the enemies should stay hurt. HTH